Unable to search with template name for elasticsearch indexes
I have been able to fetch data using a index template stack_search having pattern stack_id_* but it also has a alias with a filter for few fields.
stack_search with index pattern stack_id*
{
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "lifecycle": {
          "name": "2-week-retention"
        },
        "routing": {
          "allocation": {
            "include": {
              "_tier_preference": "data_content"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "number_of_shards": "10",
    "number_of_replicas": "1"
  },
  "aliases": {
    "stack_gssearch": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "runtimeId"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {}
}

Indexes example stack_id_202402, stack_id_202403 etc.
But I recently created a new index template log_search for indexes with pattern log* but without any alias as I need no filter. But now when I try searching data with the index template. I am getting no such index found exception.
log_search
{
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "lifecycle": {
          "name": "2-week-retention"
        },
        "routing": {
          "allocation": {
            "include": {
              "_tier_preference": "data_content"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aliases": {},
  "mappings": {}
}

I do see new indexes for log* picking up lifecycle properties from the index template. But unable to understand the linking.
Indexes example: log_test_202402, log_test_202403
I am trying the below query. I even tried with Kibana, it autopopulates stack_search but not log_search
POST log_search/_search

the question is not clear, can you please elaborate it? give example and clear the sentences. Thanks

@MusabDogan have edited with template details as well now. The issue is that the second index template is not searchable

You can update the log_search template and add aliases. Please note that the index template will add the aliases to the new indices. For existing indices you can use the _aliases API call and add alias to the existing indices.
For exiting indices
POST /_aliases?pretty
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "log_test_*",
        "alias": "log_search"
      }
    }
  ]
}

For template:
PUT _index_template/template_1
{
  "index_patterns" : ["logs*"],
  "template": {
    "aliases" : {
        "logs_search" : {}
    }
  }
}

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-template.html

does it not work without adding to aliases ?

Sorry, can you elaborate it?

My query is if I do not add aliases log_search template will it not be able to search the indexes based on the index patterns ?

Let me give you an example. GET logs*/_search API call will hit all the indices or aliases that starts with logs*. So in your case the logs* pattern will search data in log_test_202402 index and similar indices.
